# Having issues with deleting object from an array where match is found

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have the follow function that will delete object from array. It also returns the array tree without the items that was deleted. My issues is that it works when my objToFindBy is null deleting everything where {group: null} is found however it error with promise rejection if I set objToFindBy {group: 'some string'}

This code should delete all occurrences where the objToFindBy is a match, example {group: null} will find everywhere will the group is null and delete all object and then return the full tree without the objects that was deleted

```
findAndDeleteAll(tree, 'items', {group: null}) // work and delete all where match. then returns the tree without deleted objects

findAndDeleteAll(tree, 'items', {group: 'd575c91f-4765-4073-a948-5e305116610c'}) // promise rejection
```

```
const tree ={
    "type": "app",
    "info": "Custom Layout",
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "d575c91f-4765-4073-a948-5e305116610c",
        "title": "Fc",
        "group": null
      },
      {
        "id": "890d5a1e-3f03-42cd-a695-64a17b6b9bea",
        "title": null,
        "group": null
      },
      {
        "id": "cbe00537-0bb8-4837-8019-de48cb04edd6",
        "title": null,
        "group": "d575c91f-4765-4073-a948-5e305116610c",
      },
      {
        "id": "b8751c32-2121-4907-a229-95e3e49bcb39",
        "title": null,
        "group": "d575c91f-4765-4073-a948-5e305116610c"
      }
    ],
    "Children": []
  }
```

```
var findAndDeleteAll = function findAndDeleteAll(tree, childrenKey, objToFindBy) {
      var treeModified = false;
      var findKeys = Object.keys(objToFindBy);
      var findSuccess = false;
      findKeys.forEach(function (key) {
        (0, _lodash2.default)(tree[key], objToFindBy[key]) ? findSuccess = true : findSuccess = false;
      });
      if (findSuccess) {
        Object.keys(tree).forEach(function (key) {
          return delete tree[key];
        });
        return tree;
      }
      function innerFunc(tree, childrenKey, objToFindBy) {
        if (tree[childrenKey]) {
          var _loop = function _loop(index) {
            var findKeys = Object.keys(objToFindBy);
            var findSuccess = false;
            findKeys.forEach(function (key) {
              (0, _lodash2.default)(tree[childrenKey][index][key], objToFindBy[key]) ? findSuccess = true : findSuccess = false;
            });
            if (findSuccess) {
              tree[childrenKey].splice(index, 1);
              treeModified = true;
            }
            if (tree[childrenKey][index].hasOwnProperty(childrenKey)) {
              innerFunc(tree[childrenKey][index], childrenKey, objToFindBy);
            }
          };
    
          for (var index = tree[childrenKey].length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            _loop(index);
          }
        }
      }
      innerFunc(tree, childrenKey, objToFindBy);
      return treeModified ? tree : false;
    };
```

Comment: Your function would be so much simper, reusable, better, if you send not the redundant `tree` - but instead `findAndDeleteAll(tree.items, "group", null);`. think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about shorter solution?

```
const findAndDeleteAll = (tree, childrenKey, nestedKey, nestedValue) => {
  return{...tree, [childrenKey]: tree[childrenKey].filter((row) => {
    return row[nestedKey] !== nestedValue;
  })}
}
const a = findAndDeleteAll(tree, 'items', 'group', null) // work and delete all where match. then returns the tree without deleted objects

const b = findAndDeleteAll(tree, 'items', 'group', 'd575c91f-4765-4073-a948-5e305116610c') // promise rejection

console.warn(a);
console.warn(b);
```

Comment: would this solution work with deeply nested object or only shallow object

Comment: for now it is not very deep but you can modify it, using the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

Your function would be so much simper, reusable, better, if you send not the redundant `tree` - but instead `deleteFrom(tree.items, "group", null);`. think about it.

```js
const deleteFrom = (arr, pr, val) => arr.filter(ob => ob[pr] !== val);

const tree = {
  type: "app",
  info: "Custom Layout",
  items: [
    { id: "10c", title: "Fc", group: null  },
    { id: "bea", title: null, group: null  },
    { id: "dd6", title: null, group: "10c" },
    { id: "b39", title: null, group: "10c" },
  ],
  Children: []
};

const items = deleteFrom(tree.items, "group", null);

console.log(items); // Only the filtered items array

const newTree = {...tree, items};

console.log(newTree); // Your brand new tree!
```